# Can i use question mark in MySQL this way

Tags: mysql

i'm using node.js to build a web. I connect to my database (Mysql) and

get the data then return to the client side.

I know that i can use the literal template to write my sql expression like below

```
promise(`SELECT table.name FROM table WHERE name = ?`,[parameter])
```

and i'm would like to know can i write my sql expression like this?

```
promise(`SELECT table.? FROM table`,[parameter])
```

I know the result is different, i just want to know it is right or not.

thank you and have a nice day.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to parameterize database objects (tables, columns, etc.), only values.  For a more dynamic approach to database objects you'd likely need to use string concatenation, in which case be careful only to use specific whitelisted strings and not just blindly accept user input.  (That would result in a SQL injection vulnerability.)

Comment: You can use node module for this.  Link : https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-pdo

Comment: No you can't use parameters for identifiers.

Comment: @David yeah, thanks for your advice. It's helpful

Answer (score 1):

No, but you could use string interpolation like:

```
promise(`SELECT table.name FROM table WHERE name = ${parameter}`)
```

Comment: Thanks for your apply
Yes, i know string interpolation is a way, but i heard this is not a good way because it would result in a SQL injection?

Comment: Yeah I would recommend using some ORM like Sequelize if you are using a SQL database, so you don't have to write these types of SQL statements right in your code.